# SVG: Internet Explorer and pointer-events

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I am trying to implement a small SVG script that will help me implement pointer-events on IE. As my knowledge of SVG is zero I would kindly ask if somebidy can hel me.

What I need is to place a GIF, with pointer-events set to none, above a div, such that the div will receive the click when the GIF is clicked. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Pointer events only work in modern browsers and not IE. SVG did not work in IE until IE9 if that matters though it's worked for a decade or more in any other browser.